# How to get the width and height of an img element where width and height have not been set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get the width and height of an img element where width and height have not been set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't have to be explicitly set by CSS:

```
var img = document.getElementById("my_img");
var height = img.height;
var width = img.width;
```

Just like that, you have the height and width of your image element.

Answer (score 1):

Give an Id to the image(`myImage`) in the HTML and then ,

```
<img src="myimagejpg" id="myImage"/>
```

the following script will give the actuall height and width of the image...

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("myImage ");
var myheight= myImage .height;
var mywidth = myImage .width;
```